# Bind NSButton state

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, bind

I'm trying to bind the state of a `NSButton` to an `objectController`, but I can't find in Interface Builder the Voice "State" under Binds for the button.

Is there a way to bind this property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume this is a checkbox-style `NSButton`? Bind to its "value" in IB.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone wants to do two-way binding between `NSButton`'s state and, say, `NSUserDefaultsController` in Swift 2, here's how you can do this. All kudos to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3223395/458356).

```
var button: NSButton!
let userDefaults: NSObject = NSUserDefaultsController.sharedUserDefaultsController().values as! NSObject
let options: [String:AnyObject] = [NSContinuouslyUpdatesValueBindingOption: true]
button.cell!.bind("state", toObject: userDefaults, withKeyPath: "MyButtonState", options: options)
userDefaults.bind("MyButtonState", toObject: button.cell!, withKeyPath: "state", options: options)
```